# Immediate object passing and assigning as function parameter

Tags: javascript, arguments

I just wonder why this parameter is not passed as an object? Instead it's passed just as 'bbb' string. 
Is it possible to immediate assigning in function call anyway?

```
var obj = {};
var prop = 'aaa';

function foo(arg) {
    return console.log('passed: ' + arg);
}

foo(obj[prop] = 'bbb');
//expected obj.aaa = 'bbb'
```

Comment: So you want to assign `'bbb'` to `obj.aaa`, and get hold of `obj` within `foo`?

Comment: You're passing `obj.aaa` to the function, wich becomes `"bbb"`, not `obj`

Comment: When calling a function you can use any expression to specify a function parameter. An assignment is an expression that (in addition to doing the actual assignment itself) returns the value being assigned - that's also why `x = y = z = true` works...

Comment: @JamesThorpe exactly it's what I meant

Comment: Any particular reason why?  Sounds like not particularly readable code.  Is this an attempt at [a solution to some other problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), or are you just wondering if it's possible?

Comment: @JamesThorpe just curious - just wondering if it's possible in any way

Comment: `foo( (obj[prop] = 'bbb', obj) );`

Comment: @nnnnnn - peculiar but very interesting! Thank you :-)

Comment: If this is just an academic exercise then you may like to think about why `foo(obj, obj[prop] = 'bbb');` would also work (noting that I definitely wouldn't recommend doing it that way in a real program).

Comment: @nnnnnn - That works because all arguments have to be executed and widdled down to actual values that are to be passed to the function as arguments BEFORE the function is executed.

Comment: @nnnnnn now when I look at your first example `foo( (obj[prop] = 'bbb', obj) );` I'm curious why in arugments there no two properties - 'bbb' and passed object?

Comment: `foo( (obj[prop] = 'bbb', obj) );` calls `foo()` with *one* argument, the result of the expression `(obj[prop] = 'bbb', obj)` - and because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) that result will be `obj`. The extra parentheses in `(obj[prop] = 'bbb', obj)` are what causes the expression to *not* be treated as two arguments to `foo()` - whatever is in the parentheses is evaluated first and its result becomes the single argument to `foo()`. By the way, Jim was correct about why the other version works.

Comment: Thank you all for reply!